# compiling C++/CLR .NET Framework 3.5 in Visual Studio 2010 still depends on 4.0

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5, clr

I'm on our last phase of using our CPP DLL with C# but getting this dependency that prevents us from using it as .NET 3.5:

```
c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\v3.5\system.core.dll : warning C4945: 'Action' : cannot import symbol from 'c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\v3.5\system.core.dll': as 'System::Action' has already been imported from another assembly 'mscorlib'
c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll : see declaration of 'System::Action'
first seen type is used; re-order imported assemblies to use the current type
```

and

```
Error   C1197   cannot reference 'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll' as the program has already referenced 
'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll'    
PROJECTNAME L:\PROJECTNAME/MYFILE.cpp       
    PROJECTNAME c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\v3.5\system.core.dll
```

We use **Visual Studio 2010**, PlatformToolSet is set to **v100** (v90 requires 2008 to be installed) and TargetFrameWork is set to **.NET 3.5**.

How we can force compiling it using c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll and/or c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\v3.5\system.core.dll ?

Is there a way to achieve that goal?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: That is inevitable, there is managed code in the library you link when you build your program.  It implements a module initializer that ensures that the CRT is properly initialized before you can run any unmanaged code.  For VS2010 and up that library code uses .NET 4 types.  It therefore does not make sense to try to target any older version of .NET.  If 3.5 is a hard requirement (it never is) then you must build with VS2008.

Comment: Thanks @Hans - We're now switching to VS2008, facing new set of errors... handling that now.